# Is it possible to create widgets for notification center in IOS6?

Tags: iphone, ios6, widget, notifications

fellows!

Is it possible to create widgets for notification center in IOS6 without jailbreaker?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not possible without a jailbreak.